# How to filter SVN log results by subdirectory of repo?

Tags: svn

I am trying to use the SVN log command to find changes to files in a specific subdirectory/folder of my repo over a set of revisions.

Here is what I have so far:

The URL of my repo (trunk) is:

```
http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk
```

I only want to find modified/added files in the DB folder (or any subfolder of the DB folder) of the repo:

```
http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB
```

So far I have this:

```
svn log -r 300:351 -q -v --xml http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB
```

When I run this, I get files in other parts of the repo, ie in the /trunk/app folder.

Is there a way to limit the results or do I have to do some post-processing?

Comment: Which version of svn are you using? I'm (so far) unable to replicate this using v1.6.12

Comment: I am using SlikSvn: Subversion command-line client, version 1.6.17-SlikSvn-tag-1.6.17@1130896-WIN32.

Comment: I've attempted to replicate with this version of SlikSvn too and been unsuccessful. Unless...the XML output produced contains a <logentry> for every revision in the range specified where one of the actions in that commit affected a path under the URL I specified in my svn log command. NB. one <logentry> per **revision**. The other files affected under that revision's commit are also displayed. Is that what you're seeing? Can you post an example of the output you're seeing to demonstrate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm taking a punt here based on what you've described.

I suspect you're seeing paths *other* than the one you specified because **those paths were affected by an action that was committed in the same revision as a change to the path you specified.**

That being the case, **you will need to post-process the XML in order to filter out the paths you don't care about.**

Example: executing this command...

```
svn log -r 300:351 -q -v --xml http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB
```

might result in output along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="351">
<author>razlebe</author>
<date>2010-02-25T14:03:57.912308Z</date>
<paths>
<path
   kind=""
   action="D">/myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/AnotherFolder
</path>
<path
   kind=""
   copyfrom-path="/myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/AnotherFolder"
   copyfrom-rev="350"
   action="A">http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB/AnotherFolder
</path>
<path
   kind=""
   action="D">http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/SomethingElse</path>
</paths>
</logentry>
</log>
```

In this example, you're seeing a `<logentry>` element for revision 351. That revision included 3 actions:

- Deleting the folder `/myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/AnotherFolder`
- Adding the folder `http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB/AnotherFolder`
- Deleting the folder `http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/SomethingElse`

So, the XML output includes a `<logentry>` for revision 351 because that revision affected your specified URL. But because that revision also affected other paths, those paths are described in the XML too.

In other words, the `<logentry>` describes the **whole revision**; not just the bit that affects the URL you specify.

Comment: Thanks razlebe!  This is exactly what's happening.  Great explanation.

Comment: Problem here is it still tells me about files committed to other paths in the same commits. which is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

When you take a verbose log of a particular directory in Subversion, and a revision also changes a file listed outside of that directory, that file will be listed.

I believe this is what is happening in your case. That is, there's a revision in a file or directory inside the *`http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/DB`* directory that is also affecting a file in *`http://myserver/svn/repos/myproj/trunk/app`*. Thus, your log file will show both files changed in the revision.

One of the design considerations in Subversion was keeping all changes together in a single revision. In some other version control systems like Perforce, this would be considered a changeset and is the atomic constituent of a change. In other words, a change in Subversion is not a single revision of a file, but all the changes in all the files in a single revision.

In a certain sense, asking only for the changes in the `DB` directory would be meaningless and misleading. That's because a change in the `DB` also depended upon a change in the `app` directory too.

As others have suggested, you could filter the results of the *XML* file. (And if you do, I highly recommend you use a program module to do it (like [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) if you're using Perl) instead of trying to parse it via regular expressions.

However, I recommend that you think about this before moving forward since you'll be breaking the atomic structure that Subversion uses for tracking changes. You might be giving a false notion of the change taking place. For example, if someone uses your report to back out a particular change in the `DB` directory, they might have to back out the change in the `app` directory too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do some post processing. I tried to get all changes to the root node only before and had to post process it. Linq-Xml makes the job pretty easy.